# Making Thread sleep for random amount of MS

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Hey so I have 3 threads which have certain conditions when they print out something. this works fine. What I want to do now is make the thread just before it outputs something to send it to sleep for random amount of ms. I was thinking using the math class but not sure how.

the random() should generate random double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0 right ?

will I just write something like

```
Thread.sleep(random());
```

^ that doesn't work though tried it

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) takes a `long` value not `double`. You would need a typecast here: -

```
Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
```

Answer (score 15):

[`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) takes a `long` value, which is the number of milliseconds to sleep. Passing a floating-point value between zero and one won't work since the value will always get truncated to zero.

To fix this, generate a random integer from an appropriate range, and pass that to `Thread.sleep()`.

For example, to sleep for up to a second, use `Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));`. Here, `random` is an object of type [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The smallest amount of time you can `sleep()` is 1 millisecond
2. Types are incorrect: `double` vs. `long`.

This will work:

```
Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
```

It will sleep for something between 0 and 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet to sleep for a random number of milliseconds between 1000 and 2000 for example:

```java
int min = 1000;
int max = 2000;
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max));
```

The advantage of using `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...)` instead of `Thread.sleep(...)` is that it explicitly specifies the time unit (milliseconds) being used, which makes the code more readable and less error-prone.

Using `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` instead of `Math.random()` has the advantage that it is (a tiny bit) more efficient, since it doesn't require any locking mechanisms.